# Using TIdHTTPServer thread safe in D2005

Tags: indy

This question has been asked very often and I've spent hours reading, trying, testing with no result.

I guess it has to do with my older 2005 version.

Below is the code I tried after reading a post in the Embarcadero forum answered by Remy Lebeau:

[Thread: How to handle multiple HTTP sessions with Indy10 TIdHTTPServer](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=874660)

```
procedure TMainForm.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Msg : String;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.QueryParams <> '' then
  begin
    Msg := DateTimeToStr(Now) + ': ReqParam "' + ARequestInfo.QueryParams + '"';
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Msg);
      end
    );
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<HTML><BODY>Query Params found.</BODY></HTML>';
  end
  else
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<HTML><BODY>Error: No Query Params.</BODY></HTML>';
    Msg := DateTimeToStr(Now) + ': Error: No Query Params';
    TThread.Queue(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Msg);
      end
    );
  end;
end;
```

What I'm aiming for is accessing a memo or log file entry in a thread safe manner. **Somehow using `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` doesn’t compile.**

When adding the `TThread.Queue()` line as suggested by Remy, the error I get is:

> E2029 Expression expected but procedure found

Does somebody have an alternative that I can use in Delphi 2005?

Edit: this is what I see from code completion:

[image: The design view for TThread]

Comment: Please add the code snip from the pic into the question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your code as actual text, a [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If the link of your image disappears, nobody will know what your question was. By [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you help us to understand you and your question/problem better, which in turn might give you a better and more specific response. Please also read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The static versions of `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` have existed since D7 and D8, respectively, so they definitely exist in D2005. But, if you are having trouble using them, an alternative is Indy's `TIdSync` and `TIdNotify` classes, respectively.

Comment: That puzzles me, as I don't see the TThread.Synchronize at all... I've added a screenshot...

Comment: @D2005_MdK then use `TThread.StaticSynchronize()` or `TThread.StaticQueue()`, both of which are clearly visible in your screenshot.